# How do I find the 'real' area of a rectangle in a matplotlib chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two bar chart subplots in one figure. I want to know how the total areas of the bars compare between the two subplots. I know that `ax.bar()` returns a collection of Rectangle objects, and I've tried to calculate their area in the following way:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

def get_area(rects):
    area = 0
    for rect in rects:
        area += rect.get_width() * rect.get_height()
    return area

x = range(3)
y1 = [2, 3, 4]
y2 = [20, 30, 30]
r = ax1.bar(x, y1)
print "Total area of bars in first subplot = {:.1f}".format(get_area(r))
r = ax2.bar(x, y2)
print "Total area of bars in 2nd subplot = {:.1f}".format(get_area(r))
```

This prints:

```
Total area of bars in first subplot = 7.2
Total area of bars in 2nd subplot = 64.0
```

Looking at the actual figure, this is clearly not the reality I'm trying to capture.

[image: two bar chart subplots with different scales]

It seems this is giving me the areas in 'data units', but what I really care about is how much space they're using on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use `ax.transData` to translate from data coordinates to display coordinates. I found [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html) on transforms helpful in figuring this out.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def get_area(ax, rects):
    area = 0
    for rect in rects:
        bbox = rect.get_bbox()
        bbox_display = ax.transData.transform_bbox(bbox)
        # For some reason, bars going right-to-left will have -ve width.
        rect_area = abs(np.product(bbox_display.size))
        area += rect_area
    return area

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

x = range(3)
y1 = [2, 3, 4]
y2 = [20, 30, 30]
r = ax1.bar(x, y1)
print "Real area of bars in first subplot = {:.1f}".format(get_area(ax1, r))
r = ax2.bar(x, y2)
print "Real area of bars in 2nd subplot = {:.1f}".format(get_area(ax2, r))
```

New output:

```
Real area of bars in first subplot = 18417.7
Real area of bars in 2nd subplot = 21828.4
```

(Minor gotcha to be aware of: `bbox.size` can sometimes give negative width or height. It's not a problem in this repro example, but I observed it on a horizontal bar chart where the bars went from right-to-left. Better to take the absolute value to be safe.)